# ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Got value of type FLOAT64 but expected type FLOAT32 for input 0, name: serving_default_input_1:0

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite, yolov5

I am trying to testtflite model, but I am getting following error

My code looks like below

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="yolov5.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

image = cv2.imread("WIN_20230422_07_35_48_Pro.jpg")

input_shape = input_details[0]['shape'][1:3]
resized_image = cv2.resize(image, input_shape)

normalized_image = resized_image / 255.

input_data = np.expand_dims(normalized_image, axis=0)

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

print(output_data)
```

How can I convert FLOAT64 to FLOAT32?

Answer (score 2):

Try

`input_data = np.float32(input_data)`

before

```
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

print(output_data)
```

Comment: This solved my problem, should be marked accepted by the OP.